# Change Backbone view template on window resize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I want to change the template of a view on window resize, to make it responsive. This works fine when reloading the page, but I cannot update the template dynamically. As per the documents I have used this to set the template on page load:

```
getTemplate: function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024){
        this.desktopLayout = true;
        return '#MenuView';
    } else {
        this.desktopLayout = false;
        return '#MenuViewTablet';
    }
},
```

This works fine when you navigate to the page, but when the function is called on 'resize', it doesn't update the template.

Comment: Did you try to listen `onresize` event?

Comment: This is a problem that's better solved by [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @ivarni Thanks for your reply, but if you want an entirely different HTML structure, that isn't possible with media queries.

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov Yes, it is called on the resize. I have realised the error, it needs to rerender the page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm agree with @ivarni it's probably trouble with your styles/html, if you couldn't solve it with MQ

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov You need to run this.render(); once you have updated the Javascript object to render then template for screen, just in case you get in the same trouble : )

Comment: I'm use media queries for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ItemView`:

```
onShow : function () {
  $(window).on("resize.myNamespace", _.throttle(_.bind(this.render, this), 50));
},
onClose : function () {
  $(window).off("resize.myNamespace");
}
```

- Listen for window resize event
- Throttle render calls because resize event is fired very rapidly
- Bind `this` reference for render call
- Re-render view on resize; (render will call `getTemplate` again)
- Use `onShow` event so the binding only happens after the view has been inserted into the DOM
- Cleanup listener in `onClose` event to prevent errors later on, namespace to prevent collisions with other code.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive answer here is to **use Backbone's listenTo function** to listen to the **window resize event**, make your changes in that event callback, and then **ensure to call render to re-render the view**.

The most crucial step and **most common mistake** when making changes to the HTML structure of an application using Backbone **is not calling render**. If you use something like Marionette on top of Backbone, in certain circumstances your view will be automatically re-rendered when making such changes.